# making users able to add their own products wp e-commerce

Tags: plugins, e-commerce, plugin-wp-e-commerce

I am using wp e-commerce plugin to build a simple e-commerce website.

The problem is that I want to allow all users to post their products on the website.

Right now, only the admin can add products.

Does anyone know if it's possible to give users the privilege to post products?

Comment: Do you want to allow this to all visitors or just registered/logged in users?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The products are nothing but custom post type. So you have to create a custom form (say in a page template) and create custom posts accordingly in the backend.

You can have a look for the approach here:

http://wpshout.com/wordpress-submit-posts-from-frontend/

https://gist.github.com/1045695